# Как добавить еще один движущийся объект анимации Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jpanel

код который представлен ниже рисует один круг который движется вниз. Вопрос таков: Как создать еще один объект который будет двигаться в другую сторону и как реализовать возможность добавлять сколько угодно объектов со своим условием движения? Например чтобы один двигался вверх, а другой вниз или чтобы один из них двигался медленнее другого.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class TestPaint extends JFrame  {
    public TestPaint(){
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(320,345);
        setLocation(400,400);
        add(new TestField());
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPaint testPaint = new TestPaint();
    }
}
class TestField extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private final int DOT_SIZE = 1; // Размерность на сколько пикселей движется точка
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = false;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = true;
    public TestField(){
        setBackground(Color.black);
        init();
        timer = new Timer(100,this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void init(){
        x = 48;
        y = 48;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(x,y, 10, 10);
    }
    public void move(){
        if(left){
            x -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(right){
            x += DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(up){
            y -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(down){
            y += DOT_SIZE;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        move();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Насколько я понял можно просто создать еще одну фигуру со своими условными x и y в методе paintComponent и уже в методе move реализовать как будут двигаться одна и другая, но можно ли это реализовать в более сокращенном виде. Например чтобы пользователь когда захотел создать новую фигуру он записывал в аргументах чтобы фигура двигалась например налево со скоростью 5 пиксель в момент времени или какой либо другой способ который можно предложить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас в классе `TestField` вьі обрабатьіваете одну фигуру. Вам надо тут иметь дело с коллекцией фигур (например, `List<Shape>`) и в цикле вьізьівать у каждой фигурьі метод `move()` и метод `paint()`. Ну естественно, скорость и направление инкапсулировать в каждую фигуру отдельно.